# How to convert UTF-8 Hex into regular String in PHP?

Tags: php, utf-8, hex

I have some scraped data in some pretty weird shape. It looks like this:

```
%C3%96lkis
```

When converted, it should look like this:

```
Ölkis
```

I googled some, and found that **%C3%96** is presumably `UTF-8 Hex` for the character **Ö**.

There's lots of special characters in my data escaped/converted like this into different UTF-8 Hex codes.

So how do I convert it back to a normal string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your data is url encoded, you want to use PHP's urldecode function

```
urldecode("%C3%96lkis") = 'Ölkis'
```